# Updating variable on page resize

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that needs to update the number of columns when the page is resized if the user chooses the ‘auto’ option from a drop down.

Currently the drop down is binded to a variable that controls the number of columns.

````
   <select [(ngModel)]="numberOfColumnsInRow">
     <option [value]=40> 40 Per Row</option>
     <option [value]=64> 64 Per Row</option>
     <option [value]=68> 68 Per Row</option>
   </select>
 </div>```
````

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code in your ts file and do what you want in page resize

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  //your code
}
```